# How to Capture Original "Start With" ID as a Column in Oracle SQL LEVEL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Working with a large database of material being consumed as "inputs" to create various "outputs" over multiple generations. The final output (the product for market) can have potentially a dozen+ generations of inputs in its history. Each of these inputs has its own record.

Currently I'm creating a top-down view of this genealogy (meaning starting with final product and working back through all inputs) using LEVEL.

Simplified/Conceptual example of the code as follows:

```
SELECT
 OL.LOT_NAME AS output_id,
 IL.LOT_NAME AS input_id,
 LEVEL
FROM GENEALOGY_TABLE G
INNER JOIN LOT_TABLE OL
 on G.OUTPUT_LOT_KEY = OL.LOT_KEY
INNER JOIN LOT_TABLE IL
 on G.INPUT_LOT_KEY = IL.LOT_KEY
START WITH OL.LOT_NAME IN ('X', 'Y', etc...)
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR IL.LOT_NAME = OL.LOT_NAME
ORDER BY LEVEL
```

I am looking to add another column to this output table that holds the original "START WITH" value that is the origin of any the given record. Meaning that even if the record has a level of 10, I won't just see the level 9 output that that material created, but which of the multiple final products ('X', 'Y', etc... in the above example) that was ultimately created downstream.

Does Oracle have a function that can handle this? Is there a simple trick for this I'm missing? Any suggestions would be wonderful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `connect_by_root` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Query-Operators.html#GUID-95F6A554-C6FE-42CD-88A6-7A1C162ED964):

```
SELECT
 OL.LOT_NAME AS output_id,
 IL.LOT_NAME AS input_id,
 LEVEL,
 CONNECT_BY_ROOT(OL.LOT_NAME) AS STARTED_WITH
FROM GENEALOGY_TABLE G
...
```

Quick demo using HR-schema tables:

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name, manager_id, connect_by_root(manager_id)
FROM employees
START WITH manager_id in (101, 102)
CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id;

EMPLOYEE_ID LAST_NAME                 MANAGER_ID CONNECT_BY_ROOT(MANAGER_ID)
----------- ------------------------- ---------- ---------------------------
        108 Greenberg                        101                         101
        109 Faviet                           108                         101
        110 Chen                             108                         101
        111 Sciarra                          108                         101
        112 Urman                            108                         101
        113 Popp                             108                         101
        200 Whalen                           101                         101
        203 Mavris                           101                         101
        204 Baer                             101                         101
        205 Higgins                          101                         101
        206 Gietz                            205                         101
        103 Hunold                           102                         102
        104 Ernst                            103                         102
        105 Austin                           103                         102
        106 Pataballa                        103                         102
        107 Lorentz                          103                         102

16 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

With Oracle there is always a way. Use [CONNECT_BY_ROOT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators004.htm#i1035022).